# Qt painting without clearing the background

Tags: qt, background, qpainter

I'm using a QPainter to get some graphics on a window. Unfortunately every time the `paintEvent()` function is called, the whole window is cleared. How can I draw without clearing? I.e. how do I leave the stuff from previous paint event untouched?

I'm using Qt4

Comment: Which Qt version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the [`backgroundMode`](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/qt.html#BackgroundMode-enum) by using the [`setBackgroundMode`](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/qwidget.html#setBackgroundMode) setter. The `Qt::NoBackground` enum is what you are searching for.

Answer (score 5):

Since both replies are for Qt3 only, here is the solution for Qt4. You need to call

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent);
```

(for example in the constructor) following the documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum).

Answer (score 1):

In Qt3, set the `Qt::WNoAutoErase` flag from the [WidgetFlags enum](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/qt.html#WidgetFlags-enum) to avoid that the window is cleared on each paint event.

You can set this flag by passing it to the [QWidget constructor](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/qwidget.html#QWidget).

Comment: Qt Documentation says it no longer needed. So he should not use it

Comment: @Patrice: Ah, yes - in Qt4 it does not work anymore. This is a Qt3 solution.