# Qt - render QFrame with image as background without using WA_TranslucentBackground

Tags: c++, qt, qframe, qpalette

I need to set a `QFrame` with a background image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I3aG.jpg. This is what I tried:

```
setAutoFillBackground(true);
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
setStyleSheet("background: transparent;");
QPalette p = this->palette();
p.setBrush(QPalette::Base, QPixmap("ipad.png"));
this->setPalette(p);
```

This is what I am getting:

[image]

As you can see, there is an annoying black frame along the edges, which I want to remove, and view just the image. How do I do that?

P.S, it is possible to make it work by using the property `Qt:: WA_TranslucentBackground`, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30965022/qframe-with-background-image-and-otherwise-transparent-background). However, in my case, the QFrame will contain other subwidgets, some of them being QImages rendered through OpenGL, and setting `Qt:: WA_TranslucentBackground` renders those images invisible on Windows. So I am looking for a solution which does not use this property.

Edit:

Based on a solution proposed by Evgeny, I tried this (I used 325 by 400 as dimensions for the widget because those are the dimensions of the image):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QBitmap>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QLabel l;
    l.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    QPixmap p(":/img/ipad.png");
    l.setPixmap(p);
    l.setScaledContents(true);
    l.resize(300, 500); //just to test my idea
    l.setMask(p.scaled(l.width(),l.height(),Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio,
    Qt::SmoothTransformation).mask());
    l.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

With this, it appears like this:

[image]

The right side and bottom are still showing grey background. If I add `setStyleSheet("background: transparent")`, the grey background becomes black.

Comment: Possibly setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;"); will fix that.

Comment: `background` works in the same way as `background-color`. I tried both, doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe `setStyleSheet("border-image: ipad.png");` without touching widget`s palette will work?

Comment: I guess the reason is that the image is background and no transparent mask applied then. The image should be foreground.

Comment: @AlexanderVX, can you show come code to do that? Applying the mask with foreground role?

Comment: Did you try to use `QWidget::setMask`?

Comment: Can you give a working example? I tried it, doesn't work for me. But looks like it should.

Comment: @AttitudeMonger here is example from Qt documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-shapedclock-example.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I finally got a completely working example with use of `setMask`. The main problem is that your image has extra space at the border. This is the problem for OSX. At windows it works fine with original image, but for mac I had cut it.
You can get it here: [image: http://smages.com/images/pic2016010ata.png]

Then I could get working example on mac with `QFrame`.

At `.h` file:

```
#include <QFrame>
#include <QPixmap>

class TestFrame : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TestFrame(QWidget* p = 0);

protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* e) override;

private:
    QPixmap _pix;
};
```

At `.cpp` file:

```
#include <QBitmap>

TestFrame::TestFrame(QWidget *p) :
    QFrame(p, Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint),
    _pix(":/img/i2.png")
{
    QPalette pal = palette();
    pal.setBrush(QPalette::Background, QBrush(_pix));
    setPalette(pal);
    resize(_pix.width(), _pix.height());
}

void TestFrame::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e)
{
    QFrame::resizeEvent(e);
    setMask(_pix.scaled(size()).mask());
}
```

Here is screenshot on OS X

[image]

The second solution is use `QLabel` instead of `QFrame` like this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QBitmap>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QLabel l;
    l.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    QPixmap p(":/img/ipad.png");
    l.setPixmap(p);
    l.setScaledContents(true);
    l.resize(300, 500); //just to test my idea
    l.setMask(p.scaled(l.width(),l.height(),Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio,
    Qt::SmoothTransformation).mask());
    l.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will verify this. Can you provide a screenshot of your application as per this code?

Comment: I think the problem you have is that label size and image size is differs. So I have update my answer with scaled image support. You don't need scale your label, but you should set mask with scaled pixmap. Try this.

Comment: That's odd. I still have the exact same problem. Which version of Qt are you testing with? Mine is 5.3.1, 32 bit, on OS X, Yosemite. The aspect ratio may distort the image, but that should not have any effect on the background being set like you said.

Comment: By the way, your solution is not fully accurate, the background is fairly visible around the bottom and right edges, not as smooth as using `WA_TranslucentBackground`. This is the smoothness I need to achieve: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31010821/1469954

Comment: This is in Windows with Qt 5.5.1

Comment: I was mistaken, the previous solution works like a charm on Windows (you can restore that solution as well for future reference for viewers), and on Mac, while this one will work, I can use `WA_TranslucentBackground`, i.e the authentic way to make it work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: While we are at it, can you tell me how to draw a completely transparent `QFrame`/`QWidget` in Windows without `WA_TranslucentBackground`, i.e. with no image or anything as background, just transparent? I tried setting a blank `pixmap` and adding `setStyleSheet("background: transparent")`, it still shows up with a greyish white/black background rectangle. I can edit the question to include this a well (even though it was not originally mentioned).

Comment: In translucent window, even though the widget is there, it can be seen through and the background can be touched, i.e as if the widget is not there at all. I don't need that use case, I just want it to be transparent..

Comment: @AttitudeMonger I had restored second solution in my answer. Also if you like this answer pleas mark it as valid.

Comment: Did that. Can you tell me is there any way a completely transparent window (no background image or anything) an be drawn in Windows?

Comment: Afaik, this is impossible. This can be done on OS X.

Comment: With the `setMask`, you said that only those parts of the widget will be visible whose corresponding part is visible in the image. By that logic, why isn't the entire widget invisible when there is no image at all?

Comment: Are you sure that this works for all images? I tried with this image on Windows: http://imgur.com/rf5d4cj, I am seeing  white rounded outline at the rounded corners..

Comment: I think it should. But also I think that the best way is prepare mask separatly from image. Save pixmac.mask() to disk, open with image editor and make fixes. Then use this image as mask instead of pixmap.mask().

Comment: How do I make fixes? The image itself is coming here with a white background around the corners..

Answer (score 1):

The foreground image on main window (in our case with transparency bits) can be applied like that:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPixmap>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent, Qt::FramelessWindowHint)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
    setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 255);"); // preventing child widgets from not being drawn

    QLabel* pImageLabel = new QLabel;
    QPixmap pixmap(":/RnSghvV.png");
    pImageLabel->setPixmap(pixmap);

    setCentralWidget(pImageLabel);
}
```

And QLabel is derived from QFrame, so it can be applied in that same placeholder. Mind that having the main program window you need also to apply `setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true)`,

Comment: Umm, no. I said that the widget has to be a QFrame, so cannot set pixmap like that..

Comment: You can also make the frame corners round.

Comment: Just realized: QLabel is QFrame. You can create QLabel and assign the address of it to QFrame*.

Comment: Oh darn. I never knew that. I always thought `QLabel` inherits from `QWidget`. Trying it..

Comment: Strange. I made my widget inherit from QLabel instead of QFrame, and now the code is `setPixmap(QPixmap("ipad.png")); setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);`. Removed setting stylesheets and all other things mentioned in question. Now I just get a rectangular widget with grey background!

Comment: I am curious and will try some time later.

Comment: Okay, that was a formatting error. The image is coming now, but it looks the same as stated in the question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30965022/qframe-with-background-image-and-otherwise-transparent-background. And setting `background-color: none;` makes the edges black, as stated in this question.. In any case, the colored edges remain. :(

Comment: The problem resolved by applying setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true); Now I guess you wonder how to make the window movable etc. but that is a separate question.

Comment: Umm not really. The question clearly states that using `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground` makes it look as expected, but  I cannot use it for reasons I stated in question, so I need another way of doing the same...

Comment: I actually faced similar issue with WA_TranslucentBackground and the content of some child widgets was just black. The problem is solved with: setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 255);"); I updated my answer. Just a bit unsure whether applying that to global scope is sufficient but it should be.

Comment: QWidget::paintEvent()

Comment: Umm, yes, `paintEvent` is something I have already tried in conjunction with `WA_TranslucentBackground`. That is what which causes the problem to begin with. How do you propose to make it work with `paintEvent` without using `WA_TranslucentBackground`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644514/qt-painting-without-clearing-the-background

Comment: Okay, there is a solution posted to my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30965022/qframe-with-background-image-and-otherwise-transparent-background. You mean to say, I should remove the `WA_TranslucentBackground` property setting and call `setBackgroundMode` with `Qt::NoBackground`?

Comment: That is what I meant and your question was already answered? Why then you asked that again?

Comment: No it wasn't answered exactly. Originally I asked how to draw the iPad image just a standalone widget, and learnt it can be done by using `WA_TranslucentBackground`. Then while using it I found out that the OpenGL issue with `WA_TranslucentBackground` is a known one, so I need a different solution. I asked the question in a comment there, no solution could be obtained, so because it is a known issue, I thought it warrants another question.

Comment: Oh, I see. With QML window, for instance, that uses OpenGL for drawing, we use a container widget to embed it and avoid issues of intersecting with the rest of widgets. Maybe you could find a solution to your problem in a similar manner.

Comment: Okay. I am trying the `Qt::NoBackground` solution now. Will come back with the results..

Comment: It doesn't work as expected. I mean, the sub widget is displaying correctly, but the iPad image is not coming transparently, a white background is coming ai its sides, just like as shown in the image provided in the question. FYI, I did not find any enum `Qt::NoBackground`..so I am using `Qt::TransparentMode`...